# why I am getting the resultant image of depth = 5?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, javacv

I converted an RGB image into grayScale "1 channel" and then applied the guassian kernel on the image and then I sub-sampled it up to four levels "s1,s2,s3,s4" where s1 is of the highest size and s4 is of the lowest

in my task, i just need the last three levels "s2,s3,s4". after that, I resize the three Mats to be of the same size as the s2, and then I summed them up pixel by pixel, so that the result is only one Mat.

and then , i displayed some info about the resultant Mat, and they were as follows:

```
type: 5
depth: 5
channels: 3
```

and I expected the resultant Mat to be of 1 channel only. and I do not know what does depth = 5 means? i understand that the depth of the image could be 8-bits for gray scal images but what does depth = 5 mean? and why the resultant image has 3 channels

Comment: 5 == CV_32F == float. but there is something weird here: if you have 3 channels, the type should be 21==CV_32FC3. what exactly are you doing ?

Comment: @berak kindly can you please tell me how did you that 5 means CV_32F? i checked this http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.4/index.html?index-all.html  but still i do not know how did you get it

Comment: [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.4/org/opencv/core/CvType.html) are the basic ones (and i've been cheating with intellisense in c++)

Comment: @berak one more thing please, in my work, i am working with grayscale images, which CVType should i use which is suitable for grayscale image?

Comment: usually, CvType.CV_8U is grayscale, but some operations, like Sobel() or filter2D() will result in float images

Comment: @berak yes i have to apply also filter2D operations on the image, in this case which is recommended

Comment: keep it as float as long as nessecary, use `convertTo()` before you save or draw it